# Weird stepping in bump map despite using 32-bit bump map image

Tags: texturing, normal-map, bump

i am trying to get rid of these steps in my bump map. Someone told me these steps occur because 8 bit isnt enough because it only contains 256 colors. So I increased the bit depth to 32 and tried several noise removing and gaussian blur methods but these steppings are still there and I don't know how to smooth them out. Even setting the Texture interpolation to Cubic only removes some steppings but not all.

How do I get rid of these steppings?

[image: This is my problem. This is when interpolation is set on Linear]

This is my problem. This is when interpolation is set on Linear

[image: And this is when interpolation is set on Cubic or Smart. Only a few steppings got smoothed out but not all.]

And this is when interpolation is set on Cubic or Smart. Only a few steppings got smoothed out but not all.

Comment: Is the bump map normalized?

Comment: Increasing the bit depth of an image alone doesn't do anything, if your source had limited precision-- you can't create detail by turning an 8 bit image into a 32 bit image (or by converting a .jpg into a .png.)  And a gaussian blur isn't necessarily going to smooth things out (it will make discontinuities in the slope unless the slope is a very particular one appropriate to a gaussian blur.)  When you say you increased the bit depth, what exactly do you mean?